# accept nested attributes for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below are my two model classes

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :enrollments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :clients, :through => :enrollments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments
  attr_accessible :user_attributes,:enrollments_attributes, :insurance
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :patient
  attr_accessible :client_id, :patient_id, :patient_id, :active 
end
```

In my patient form I would like to have a multi select box where a patient can be assigned to clients. Is there a way this can be done so I don't have to have any logic in the 
controller except for

```
@patient = Patient.new(params)
@patient.save
```

I have tried this:

```
<%= patient_form.fields_for :enrollments do |enrollments_fields| %>
<tr>
    <td class="label">
        <%= enrollments_fields.label :client_id %>:                     
    </td>
    <td class="input">
        <%= enrollments_fields.collection_select(:client_id, @clients, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true) %>
    </td>                   
</tr>
<% end %>
```

But it only saves the first client. If I remove the multiple part, it functions but I can only select 1 client!

The html value of the select is:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag "patient[client_ids][]", client.id, @patient.clients.include?(client) %>
```

I am not sure if this is the best way...any comments (I had to update my model to include attr_accessible :client_ids

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 3 (not sure about previous versions) you don't even need to use accepts_nested_attributes_for to accomplish this. You can simply remove all the view code you listed and replace it with the following:

```
<%= patient_form.select(:client_ids, @clients.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {}, {:multiple => true})%>
```

Rails will do its magic (because of you named the select "client_ids") and it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
:client_id
```

in the collection_select, try

```
"client_id[]"
```

The second form specifies that you're accepting an array of IDs for the attribute rather than a single one.

Here's a good resource on the usage of the select helpers in forms: http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I got this error:
undefined method `:client_id[]' for #<Enrollment:0x1068aae38>

Comment: I don't think you need to make a symbol, just a straight string. "client_id[]"

Comment: undefined method `client_id[]' for #<Enrollment:0x10653f410>

Comment: OK, I was hoping you could skate by without having to manually build the form, but I guess that won't happen. The basic idea is that name attribute of a field in a form tells Rails how to structure the params hash.
So, in your case, you'd need to use a select_tag rather than collection_select and pass your @clients collection to options_for_select helper method.
Name it properly and you should be good. Check here as to how to name properly, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#basic-structures