# RoR - Resource to learning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having the following problem: i have a lot of tables, some of then are nested and other aren't. I divided my app in some areas that i think that is the correct way. One area should manipulate some tables at the same time, at the same action, like i said: some models are nested others not. What is the best solution in Rails world?
What should i read to get the point?

I tried to use

```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

and i tried build the objects to use at the same form with fields_for. But it's going to be a complex form because some objects contains foreign keys and unfortunately i can't get the correct builds with more than 2 objects.

I'll keep trying.

Thanks!

----edit-----

```
    Class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :states
      attr_accessible :nome
      # i tried # accepts_nested_attributes_for :state
    end

    Class State < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :country
      has_many :cities
      attr_accessible :nome, :country_id
      # i tried # accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
      # i tried # accepts_nested_attributes_for :country # too
    end
```

The models continues until we get the adress model:

```
    Class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :bairros_logradouros # we name streets, avenues, parks as logradouros
                                    # here in Brasil, the others models are translated
                                    # to EN here
      has_many :logradouros, :trough => :bairros_logradouros # many-to-many

      attr_accessible :number, :complement, :other, :another 

      # i tried # accepts_nested_attributes_for :logradouro
    end
```

The setup: Country -> State -> City -> District(bairro, here) -> :Logradouro <-> Adress.
I tried to build the chain in both direction, but i only get 2 objects, the third brings a nil problem with the build method.

These tables are about adress, i should manipulate the User model tha has_one Person that, at the end has an adress, i would like to point the adress at the :addres_id inside Person.

All this must be manipulated at the custom Data controller, all CRUDs here.

I couldn't build the entire chain:

```
    @addres = @addres.new
    @other = @addres.logradouros.build
    @another = @other.build_district
    @even_more = @another.build_city
    ....
```

I learned to use objects.build and build_object, but i couldn't build more than 2 nested objects.

I'm a newbie.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post some code?  Please include your models/associations as well as the relevant controller and view code.

Comment: Well, i'm at another computer right now, but i'll edit the question and put some more examples.

Comment: Edited- There's some examples above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great place to start:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answear. I took that railsbook tutorial but i didn't find a similar problem or solution. Maybe my new informations at the questions helps me to express what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mass assignment whitelisting in Rails 3.1+ (up to but not including Rails 4) then if you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :logradouros` you need to have `attr_accessible :logradouros_attributes` (notice the plural logradouros and the _attributes in the name). But, you may have more problems than that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197761/accept-nested-attributes-for-has-many-relationship) is a related question.

A good reference when starting out is to read everything in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).