# Using HABTM or Has_many through with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I've read quite a few of the posts on using active admin with has_many through association but I'm not getting the desired results. Essentially I have 2 models "Conferences" & "Accounts". I need to assign multiple accounts to a conference and multiple conferences to an account. Wether I use HABTM or has_many through doesn't matter to me. I just need to be able to see a dropdown select option when I create a new conference and vice versa on accounts.

**Account Model**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :name, :phone, :state, :website, :zip
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :conferences, :through => :conferenceaccount
end
```

**Conference Model**

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :conferencename, :eventdateend, :eventdatestart, :industry, :phone, :state, :website
  has_many :accounts, :through => :conferenceaccount
end
```

**Conference Account Model**

```
class Conferenceaccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conference
  belongs_to :account

  attr_accessible :account_id, :conference_id
end
```

**Conference Admin Model**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Conference do 
  form do |f|
      f.inputs "Details" do # Project's fields
          f.input :conferencename
          f.input :address
          f.input :city
          f.input :state         
          f.input :website
          f.input :phone
          f.input :eventdatestart
          f.input :eventdateend
          f.input :industry         
      end
      f.has_many :conferenceaccounts do |app_f|
         app_f.inputs "Conferences" do
           if !app_f.object.nil?
             # show the destroy checkbox only if it is an existing appointment
             # else, there's already dynamic JS to add / remove new appointments
             app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
           end

           app_f.input :account # it should automatically generate a drop-down select to choose from your existing patients
         end
       end      
      f.buttons
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
  app/admin/conferences.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi why you use `:through` in model?

`:through`useful for Many-to-Many Associations for ex: `has_many :replies, :through => :articles, :source => :comments` 

`:replies` is alias for call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to add below lines to your Conference model?

```
# conference.rb
attr_accessible : conferenceaccounts_attributes
has_many :conferenceaccounts

# This line after your your relations
accepts_nested_attributes_for : conferenceaccounts, :allow_destroy => true
```

see: [accept nested attributes for has_many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197761/accept-nested-attributes-for-has-many-relationship)

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same error when I try to create a new conference object. Additionally nothing shows up to filter by on the show page

Comment: Ah, it should be "conferenceaccounts", and you might need to add has_many :conferenceaccounts in conference model. Fixed, please try now :)

Comment: Btw, what filters do you want to add? You mean filters on Index page?

Answer (score 1):

When using `has_many through: :some_model`, make sure to define has_many on `:some_model` also, for example:

If you have:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conferences, :through => :conferenceaccount
end
```

Transform it into:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conferences, :through => :conferenceaccount
  has_many :conferenceaccount                              # <- added
end
```