# Selecting 'has_many through' associations in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin, has-many-through

I've seen several questions asked about this along the same vein, e.g.

[Using HABTM or Has_many through with Active Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432857/using-habtm-or-has-many-through-with-active-admin)

but I'm still struggling to get things to work (I've tried multiple ways at this point).

My models (slightly complicated by the 'technician' alias for the user model):

```
class AnalysisType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :analysis_type_technicians, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :technicians, :class_name => 'User', :through => :analysis_type_technicians
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :analysis_type_technicians, allow_destroy: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :analysis_type_technicians, :foreign_key => 'technician_id', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :analysis_types, :through => :analysis_type_technicians
end

class AnalysisTypeTechnician < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :analysis_type, :class_name => 'AnalysisType', :foreign_key => 'analysis_type_id' 
  belongs_to :technician, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'technician_id'
end
```

I have registered an ActiveAdmin model for the AnalysisType model and want to be able to select (already created) Technicians to associate with that AnalysisType in a dropdown/checkbox. My ActiveAdmin setup currently looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AnalysisType do
  form do |f|
    f.input :analysis_type_technicians, as: :check_boxes, :collection => User.all.map{ |tech|  [tech.surname, tech.id] }
    f.actions
  end 

  permit_params do
    permitted = [:name, :description, :instrumentID, analysis_type_technicians_attributes: [:technician_id] ]
    permitted
  end

end
```

Whilst the form seems to display okay, the selected technician does not get attached upon submitting. In the logs I'm getting an error 'Unpermitted parameters: analysis_type_technician_ids'.

I've tried multiple ways of doing this following advice in other related SO pages but am always coming up against the same issue, i.e. unpermitted parameterd of some nature. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? (I'm using Rails 4 by the way)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Managing the association via `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many` relations
does not require the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. This type of form
input is managing the Technician IDs associated with the AnalysisType record.
Defining your permitted parameters and form like the following should allow
those associations to be created.

```
ActiveAdmin.register AnalysisType do
  form do |f|
    f.input :technicians, as: :check_boxes, collection: User.all.map { |tech| [tech.surname, tech.id] }
    f.actions
  end

  permit_params :name, :description, :instrumentID, technician_ids: []
end
```

In the case where the creation of new Technician records is required that is
when the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` would be used.

---

**Note**: Updated answer to match comments.

Comment: I think your suggestion is how I actually started out. But having tried it again I'm still getting an 'unpermitted parameters' error on the :analysis_type_technicians_id. The following is being returned from the form:

"analysis_type"=>{"name"=>"fsdfds", "instrumentID"=>"fsdfsdfds",    "description"=>"fsdfds", "analysis_type_technician_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Update Analysis type", "id"=>"2"}.

Am I using the permit_params in the wrong way? Or do I need to put this these at the controller/model level too?

Comment: You're right. Changing the permitted_params to `:analysis_type_technician_ids => []` for the that field should do the trick.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't we be targeting technicians directly, i.e. 'f.input :technicians......' along with 'permit_params......, :technician_ids'? When I do that things work fine, otherwise it complains that it can't find the :analysis_type_technician_ids (which I think makes sense).

Comment: That should work if the `:through` relation is simple and records can be created via the `technicians` relation. Occasionally there are complication that require more work, such as validations, that prevent records from being created through a `:through` relation.