# Multiple File Upload ActiveAdmin Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a form that has 3 models (1 for the actual form, 1 for other entries and another for the uploaded archives). I want to use jQuery File Upload gem to upload my PDFs to the server, but I'm also using the ActiveAdmin gem that handles this forms.

How can I create a multi-upload file input and add that through my Files model inside ActiveAdmin?

I should have:

- Validates if the file is a PDF
- Validates his size
- Submit everything together with the form ( if the form has an error, don't upload but keep the files inside the input )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a form with multiple uploads you can try this:

```
# active admin
form do |f|
  f.inputs "ModelName" do 
    f.input :name
  end
  f.has_many :attachments do |ff|
    ff.input :path
  end
end

# your_model.rb
attr_accessible :attachments_attributes
has_many :attachments

# your_model.rb (add after relations)
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true
```

see also: [accept nested attributes for has_many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197761/accept-nested-attributes-for-has-many-relationship)

Use of rails validators will hinder the form from being saved if not passed.

```
# attachment.rb  
validates :check_size 
validates :check_if_pdf 

def check_size
  errors.add :path, "Size is NOT ok" if self.size < XXX
end

def check_if_pdf 
  errors.add :path, "File is NOT pdf" unless self.path.to_s.split('.').last == 'pdf'
end
```

Not sure about Paperclip...Carrierwave is awesome as well and if you are open to that gem you can try this:

```
# attachment.rb
mount_uploader :path, MyUploader

# app/uploaders/my_uploader.rb
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file  # For local storage
  #storage :fog  # If using S3

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{File.basename(original_filename, '.*')}" if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

Carrierwave has an extension_white_list method that you can try to validate that its a PDF document

```
 # uploaders/my_uploader.rb
 def extension_white_list
   %w(pdf jpg jpeg gif png csv )
 end
```

Comment: That was very helpful, after that, how can I upload the multiple files with Paperclip and the activeAdmin gem?

Comment: Ok, added some lines in case you wanna change to Carrierwave.

Comment: Thanks again, can I add you on Skype? I'm really new to the Rails world.